# Como imprimir texto na mesma linha em Python

Tags: python

```
    list = open("list.txt", "w")
    list = list.readlines()
    for i in list:
       print i
```

Gostaria de Imprimir o valor de **i** na mesma linha, sem ficar descendo. Tipo substituindo a palavra atual.

Comment: Coloque um exemplo de output esperado

Answer (score 13):

Uma solução é utilizar o parâmetro `end` da função `print` igual à `\r`. Isso faz com que o ponteiro volte ao início da mesma linha; porém isso não faz com que a linha seja apagada. As linhas iriam se sobrescrever uma a uma e se ocorrer de uma linha tentar sobrescrever uma linha maior que ela, caracteres *lixos* ficariam sendo exibidos. Para certificar-se que isso não ocorra, basta limpar a linha atual com o caractere `\033[k`. Veja o exemplo:

Considerando um arquivo *frases.txt* com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Integer vitae mi interdum mauris ultricies venenatis sit amet eget sapien.
Proin sit amet ante ornare, ornare lectus sit amet, faucibus velit.
Nulla ac risus sit amet tortor vulputate congue et id urna.
Proin et nisl non dui tristique pretium.
Etiam fringilla erat id ullamcorper euismod.
Donec accumsan dolor nec nibh dictum gravida.
Etiam sed lorem non leo condimentum dictum.
Donec posuere nisl in imperdiet molestie.
Donec vel metus sollicitudin, interdum odio non, egestas neque.
Donec eleifend odio laoreet consequat ornare.
Vestibulum rutrum metus nec sollicitudin condimentum.
```

Fazemos:

```
import time

# Abre o arquivo frases.txt como leitura:
with open("frases.txt") as frases:

    # Percorre as linhas do arquivo:
    for frase in frases:

        # Limpa a linha atual, exibe a linha, retorna o ponteiro para o início:
        print("\033[K", frase.strip(), end="\r")

        # Tempo de 1s para poder visualizar a frase:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Importante: exibimos o valor de `frase.strip()`, pois a frase possuirá um caractere `\n` no seu final e se o mantivermos, cada linha do arquivo será exibida em uma linha diferente do terminal. Com o método `strip` removemos este caractere.

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Vale a pena falar do caractere `\b` também - ele volta uma coluna o cursor, e funciona também em terminais onde as ansi sequences não estão ativas. (essa dúvida é frequente, eu respondi isso em outra questão recentemente também)

Comment: @jsbueno Bem lembrado, verei se completo a resposta

Answer (score 5):

Altere o seu print(i) para

```
print(i, end=" ")
```

Para Python 2 utilize:

```
print i,
```

Comment: Esta solução apenas exibirá uma linha atrás da outra, semelhante ao processo de concatenação. A pergunta pede para que a linha exibida anteriormente seja apagada e substituída pela atual.