# Escrever e apagar texto no terminal do python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um experimento no Python 3.6.2 que é um contador no terminal, mas quero exibir a contagem sempre na mesma posição. Tentei inserir a *string* usando a função *print* e depois apagar o mesmo texto e reescrever o texto substituto.

Primeiro fiz o experimento sem a contagem de tempo.

```
text = ''
for i in range(10):
    text += '{} - '.format(i)

print(text, end='')
print('\b\b\b', end='', flush=True)
```

Observem que após o laço a string text termina com ' - ', entretanto a ideia é usar o traço apenas para separar os números, então coloco três caracteres de *backspace* para apagar esses caracteres, a saída final do programa fica assim:

```
0 - 1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - 8 - 9
```

Agora fiz um novo programa com uma espera de um segundo entre uma exibição e a outra usando a função *sleep* do módulo *time*.

```
from time import sleep

for i in range(10):
    line = str(i)
    print(line, end='', flush=True)
    sleep(1)
    print('\b' * len(line), end='', flush=True)
```

Eu esperava que os valores de *i* aparececem no terminal e depois fossem apagados para que o próximo pudesse aparecer no mesmo lugar. Mas ao invés disso eu obtive cada valor aparecendo em uma nova linha, sendo que eu removi o caracter final padrão do função *print* pelo uso do parâmetro *end*. Segue a saída:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Afinal, como eu faço para os números aparecerem no mesmo lugar?

Comment: Seria isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207887/5878

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, entretanto eu teste aqui e essa solução e não funcionou, então eu fui rodar o script pelo terminal e descobri que o problema ocorreu por causa do PyCharm, no terminal funciona normal, tanto essa solução que você colocou como a minha própria. Muito obrigado.