# Como comparar se um número digitado pelo usuário é igual a determinado valor

Tags: python

Tenho este código:

```
idade = input('Qual a sua idade? ')
if(idade == 33):
    print('Ok, não parece que você está mentindo.')
else:
    print('Você tem certeza que não pulou alguns dígitos?')
```

Independente da idade que eu coloque, o código executa o `else` - mesmo quando insiro a resposta correta - que no caso seria 33.

Comment: O problema é que `input` retorna uma string, então precisa converter para número, conforme já explicado na duplicada sugerida no box azul acima. Removi a outra parte da pergunta (sobre voltar a linha no terminal) porque a ideia do site é ter um problema específico por pergunta, mas em todo caso, talvez isso ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207887/112052 | https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/72678/112052

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz:

```
idade = input('Qual a sua idade? ')
```

Você está atribuindo uma **string** à variável **idade** e, portanto, o seu código nunca irá executar o `if`. Pois, o `if` só será executado se a **idade** for do tipo `int`. Dessa forma, o código sempre executará o `else`.

Por padrão, a função **[input()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#input)** sempre retorna uma string. Por isso, para consertar este problema, basta converter o valor capturado para inteiro - **int**. Tal como listado na primeira linha do código abaixo.

```
idade = int(input('Qual a sua idade? '))
if idade == 33:
    print('Ok, não parece que você está mentindo.')
else:
    print('Você tem certeza que não pulou alguns dígitos?')
```

Observe que a primeira linha de código captura o valor digitado e converte para inteiro e, só em seguida, realiza as verificações.

Outra coisa, os parênteses que você tinha colocado na linha do `if` são desnecessários.

---

Agora para você reexecutar o código, você pode envolve-lo em um bloco `while True`. Desta forma o código ficaria:

```
while True:
    idade = int(input('Qual a sua idade? '))
    if idade == 33:
        print('Ok, não parece que você está mentindo.')
    else:
        print('Você tem certeza que não pulou alguns dígitos?')
    
    while (resp := input('Desejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()) not in {'S', 'N'}:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')
    if resp == 'N':
        break
```

Observe que o código será reexecutado todas as vezes que sua resposta for `s` ou `S`.

Observe que as linhas de código...

```
while (resp := input('Desejas continuar? [S/N] ').upper()) not in {'S', 'N'}:
        print('Valor INVÁLIDO!')
```

...formam um recurso disponibilizado pelo **Python 3.8** ou superior que se chama
**[Assignment Expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)**.

Esta linhas de código verifica se a expressão atribuída à variável `resp` é `S` ou `N`. Caso o valor de **resp** não seja nem `S` e nem `N`, receberemos a mensagem `Valor INVÁLIDO` e seremos novamente solicitado uma resposta. Caso seja `S`, o código será reexecutado. Caso, seja `N`, o código será finalizado.

Comment: Obrigado pelas respostas. Vou por em prática suas dicas Solkarped, valeu!